# Averaging piped numbers from sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am working on a command that grabs the latest cpu percentage from top then averages the load from all cpus to produce a total percentage of cpu load. The command I currently have is...

```
top -bn2 | awk '/Cpu/ {print $4}' | sed 's/[\[|]//g;'
```

And an example output is here...

```
11
12
5
5
```

For whatever reason the first two numbers always remain the same. So at this point what I need to do is average the last two numbers in this list and append a percentage sign. What would be the ideal way to do this? I'd prefer to use awk if possible, but I am not well versed in awk so I could use some help. Thanks!

Comment: Those `top` options produce an error for me on FreeBSD and OSX, and produce non-numeric output on an old Linux VM I have on hand.  Please include a sample of the text you're trying to process with awk and sed.

Comment: The column of numbers in the post is a sample output from my machine, it is output in just that format as well.

Comment: output `1.3% \n
1.1%` on linux.

Comment: How do "the first two numbers always remain the same"?  I see `11` and `12` which, last I checked, were not the same.  And the average of the set `(5, 5)` would be ... `5`.  Is that what you're looking for, only presented with a percent?

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear. When run multiple times, the first two outputs remain the same, consistently. For instance, when running the command, I have received the top two values 10/10 times. This seems to be an issue with the top command when you use the batch option, and why I have sampled the batch twice, since it is only in the second batch that I receive a varied sample, and likely the only time I am getting an actual representation of cpu usage.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you need to clarify your source data.  No processing will generate useful output until you understand and can trust your input. [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is simply to average the last two numbers a set of four, the following awk should suffice:

```
awk 'NR<=2 {print;next} {n+=$1} END {printf("%.2f%%\n", n/(NR-2))}'
```

You can adjust the output format to suite your needs.

If you don't want to print the first two lines, you could simplify this to:

```
awk 'NR>2 {n+=$1} END {printf("%.2f%%\n", n/(NR-2))}'
```

Technically, this just skips the first two lines, sums the remaining lines (or rather, the first word on those lines), then once there are no more lines to process, prints the sum divided by two less than the number of lines processed.  So it will work for more than 2 lines if you want it to.

Again, the `%.2f` format gives you a floating point number with two decimal places.  If you want to adjust that, you can do so according to the documentation in the awk or printf man pages.

**UPDATE**:

Breakdown of the awk script.

The first thing to understand is of course how awk works.  An awk script is composed of a series of `condition {statement}` pairs.  For each "record" of input (usually a line of text), awk steps through each of the conditions one by one, and if they evaluate to true, awk executes the associated statement.

In this case, we have a condition, `NR>2`, which evaluates to true if the current record number is greater than two.  In other words, no statements are executed until the second line of input has passed.  After this point, the statement `{n+=$1}` is run, which adds to the variable `n` the value of the first "word" (delimited by whitespace by default) of the current line.

After all lines of input have been exhausted, the magic condition `END` is matched.  Statements in this section are run after all input is done.  And the statement `{printf("%.2f%%\n", n/(NR-2))}` prints the variable we added up earlier in the script, divided by the number of records (lines) minus 2.  This is the average of all lines skipping the first two.

Clear?

Comment: Thank you! The second command outputs exactly what I was looking for, since I needed to ignore the first two numbers and average the last two. Any chance I could get a break down of the command?

Comment: Yes! It makes a lot more sense now.